# C# FilePath Help

Tags: c#, winforms, openfiledialog

I use OpenFileDialog to search for a specific file.  When the user chooses the file, I want to store that path in a variable.  However, these doesn't seem to be an option for this within OpenFileDialog?

Does anybody know how to do this?

Thanks.

Edit:  This is Winforms, and I don't want to save the path inclusive of the filename, just the location where the file is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will retrieve your path based on the `FileName` property of the `OpenFileDialog`.

```
String path = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(OpenFileDialog.FileName);
```

Answer (score 5):

If you are using WinForms, use the `FileName` property of your `OpenFileDialog` instance.

Comment: That property doesn't exist in SL just as an FYI; not sure what the OP is using...

Comment: and finally String path = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(FileName);

Answer (score 4):

On WinForms:

```
String fileName;
OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
DialogResult dr = ofd.ShowDialog();
if (dr == DialogResult.Ok) {
  fileName = ofd.FileName;
}

//getting only the path:
String path = fileName.Substring(0, fileName.LastIndexOf('\\'));

//or easier (thanks to Aaron)
String path = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(fileName);
```

Comment: That includes the file name, which I don't want.  Just the path that the file is contained in.  I should have been a little clearer.

Comment: No need to substring; String path = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(fileName);

Answer (score 1):

Instead of copy pasting answers from MSDN I'll just link to them.

MSDN documentation on [Forms OpenFileDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.openfiledialog.aspx).

MSDN documentaiton on [WPF OpenFileDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.openfiledialog%28VS.95%29.aspx).

Please try to look for a answer before posting questions.

Answer (score 1):

You store the path ... somewhere else!

What I usually do is create a user-scoped configuration variable.

[image]

Here's a sample of its use:

```
var filename = Properties.Settings.Default.LastDocument;
var sfd = new Microsoft.Win32.SaveFileDialog();
sfd.FileName = filename;
/* configure SFD */
var result = sfd.ShowDialog() ?? false;
if (!result)
    return;
/* save stuff here */
Properties.Settings.Default.LastDocument = filename;
Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
```

---

To save just the directory, use [System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getdirectoryname.aspx)

Comment: Thanks, your final suggestion pointed me in the right direction.  I used  System.IO.Directory.GetParent(openFileDialog1.FileName).ToString();  And that works perfectly.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

After the dialog closes there should be a file path (or something similar) property on the OpenFileDialog object, it will store whatever file path the user entered.

Answer (score 0):

Try FileName. Or FileNames if you allow multiple files to be selected(Multiselect=true)